# How to put thumbnail on the video?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

Does someone knows how to put thumbnail on the video? I have local files on my windows' laptop, but there are no thumbnails on it, so someone knows how to put thumbnails on it?

Comment: What format and codec are the videos in? (Screenshot the VLC "media info" window for example.)

Comment: https://ibb.co/qrLbbtj
This is the information of the video.

Comment: Yeah, but can you show the part of the window that shows the codec and format information?

Comment: I don't know how to check that, can you tell me how can I check it?

Comment: https://ibb.co/qrLbbtj
Are you referring to this?

Comment: The "Codec" tab at the top? Though I can guess from the file name that it's HEVC, either way.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Windows doesn't have built-in support for the HEVC (H.265) video codec; you need to install it either from [Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NMZLZ57R3T7?hl=en-US&gl=US) (for Windows Media Foundation) or from a [codec pack](https://codecguide.com/about_kl.htm) (for the older DirectShow system) or both.

Either of the above should provide file thumbnailing, though actual players will use one or the other. (VLC uses neither, it includes its own.)

Comment: I have installed the codec pack, but still there is no thumbnail on the video see. 
https://ibb.co/HxVzP0s